# Sending multiple files via python ports randomly hangs up

Tags: python, network-programming, ports

I've had very unusual behavior with my server sending files to clients (it has no problems receiving from them). To make matters worse, it hangs up at seemingly random times. Sometimes transferring 100's of files and sometimes only 1-3.

**Where it hangs up: At the client code definition receiveFile at the "l = s.recv(512)" inside the while loop**

**EDIT: Some important info. When i run the client code on the server it doesn't hang up!**

So obviously the client is waiting for some kind of input and the server is not giving anymore data? But why would the server function not give anymore data? I'm obviously missing something obvious? Why is it randomly hanging up?

I'm trying to transfer 4000 relatively small files from my server to a client. The file sizes range from to 981B to 37.0kB.

I've tried changing the bytes sent/received a time with no affect.

I know it is a tall order but any attempt at helping is GREATLY appreciated (worked on this for a week now with no avail)

Server Code:

```
import socket
import os
import sys
import time
import thread
import easygui
import os.path
import MySQLdb
from socket import error as socket_error
from random import randint


serverIP = "192.168.1.65"

class fileConnection(object):
    def connect(self, clientsocket):
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        connected = False
        while not connected:
            try:
                port = randint(1024,2024)
                sock.bind((serverIP,port))
                connected = True
            except socket_error:
                None
        return sock

    def receiveFile(self, fileName, clientsocket):
        s = self.connect(clientsocket)
        s.listen(5)
        clientsocket.send(str(s.getsockname()[1]).ljust(5)[0:5])
        c, addr = s.accept()

        fout = open(fileName,'wb')
        l = c.recv(512)
        while (l):
            fout.write(l)
            l = c.recv(512)
        fout.close()

        s.shutdown(2) #has to be 2
        #s.close() #is this causing problems?

    def sendFile(self, fileName, clientsocket):
        s = self.connect(clientsocket)
        s.listen(5)
        clientsocket.send(str(s.getsockname()[1]).ljust(5)[0:5])
        c, addr = s.accept()

        fin = open(fileName,'rb')       
        l = fin.read(512)
        while (l):
            c.send(l)
            l = fin.read(512)
        fin.close()

        s.shutdown(1) #works for 1 and 2 AND without. Maybe doesnt need this...
        #s.close()


def client_thread(clientsocket, file_names):
    file_name = file_names.pop()
    clientsocket.send(file_name.ljust(64)[0:64])
    connect = fileConnection()
    connect.sendFile("./folder/" + file_name, clientsocket)




##################################################
#puts filenames in fileNames
##################################################
file_names = []
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk("./folder/"):
    file_names.extend(filenames)
    break
##################################################

serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
serversocket.bind((serverIP, 9999))
serversocket.listen(5)

print "Listening for jobs to send...\n"


while True:
    (clientsocket, address) = serversocket.accept()
    ct = thread.start_new_thread(client_thread,(clientsocket, file_names,))
```

Client Code:

```
import easygui
import os.path
import socket
import sys
import os
import time
import errno
from socket import error as socket_error
import tarfile
import shutil
from timeout import timeout

serverIP = "192.168.1.65"

class fileConnection(object):
    def connect(self, client_socket):
        port = int(client_socket.recv(5).strip())
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        connected = False
        while not connected:
            try:
                sock.connect((serverIP,port))
                connected = True
            except socket_error:
                print "Couldn't connect to server. Trying again in 5 seconds"
                time.sleep(5)
        print port
        return sock

    def receiveFile(self, fileName, client_socket):     
        s = self.connect(client_socket)
        fout = open(fileName,'wb')
        l = s.recv(512)
        while (l):
            fout.write(l)
            l = s.recv(512)
        fout.close()
        s.close()
        #time.sleep(0.25)
        return True

    def sendFile(self, fileName, client_socket):
        s = self.connect(client_socket)
        fin = open(fileName,'rb')
        l = fin.read(512)
        while (l):
            s.send(l)
            l = fin.read(512)
        fin.close()
        s.close()
        #time.sleep(0.25)
        return True


def test_receive_file(client_socket):
    file_name = client_socket.recv(64).strip()
    print file_name
    connect = fileConnection()
    connect.receiveFile("./folder/" + file_name, client_socket)
    return file_name

while True:
    #time.sleep(.1)

    client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    client_socket.connect((serverIP, 9999))
    file_name = test_receive_file(client_socket)
    client_socket.close()
```

Comment: Why dont you use [SocketServer](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/socketserver.html#socketserver-tcpserver-example) (with [ThreadingMixin](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/socketserver.html#SocketServer.ThreadingMixIn)) for the server? It would make your code simpler. (Although this might not actually help, If you are transmitting file-likes I would suggest using [WSGIServer](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/wsgiref.html#wsgiref.simple_server.WSGIServer) with [ThreadingMixin](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/socketserver.html#SocketServer.ThreadingMixIn) plus urllib2)